# Почему оператор= возвращает объект того же экземпляра класса, для которого он вызывается?

Tags: c++

Предположим есть некий класс который управляет неким ресурсом и у нас есть следующий код для оператора присваивания.

```
Resource& Resource::operator=(const Resource& rhs)
{
    this->someProperty = rhs.someProperty;
    return *this;
}
```

Вопрос, зачем нужно возвращать *this?
Ну присвоили мы, и все хорошо:

```
Resource resource1;
Resource resource2;
resource1 = resource2;
```

Зачем самого себя еще возвращать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это нужно для того чтобы была возможность писать так:

```
first = second = third
```

Если вы объявите в качестве типа возвращаемого значения void, то не сможете полученному результату какое-либо значение/ Маленький пример:

```
class  Int {
 public :
    int Variable;

    void operator= (const int& rhs);
};

void Int::operator= (const int& rhs)
{
    this->Variable = rhs;       
}

Int i, g;
i.Variable = 10;
g.Variable = 10;

i = 30;     // так можно
i = g = 30; // а так нельзя
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ уже есть на [SOV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072169/why-should-the-assignment-operator-return-a-reference-to-the-object)
Как и сказал @DreamChild без возврата ссылки на объект вы не сможете сделать следующее:

```
Resource resource1;
Resource resource2;
Resource resource3;
resource1 = resource2 = resource3;
```

Comment: кажется это называется chaining, я понял, спасибо